# Best Practice for Testing TFS Build Definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have searched high and low* for a good tutorial or best practices for testing Build Definition changes in TFS. When making changes, I don't want to flood the build agents, but more importantly I don't want to keep creating packages and generating emails to developers, especially when the build fails.

Is there a best practice for developing and testing build definitions, so as to not interfere with existing development?

*The problem is whenever you search for "test" and "build" together, everything is about setting up unit tests within builds.

Comment: Are you talking about creating new build templates or editing the settings of a build definition using an existing template?

Comment: If you want to completly seperate build testing from real tfs, you will have to setup a seperate collection with its own build controller. Or go for whole seperate tfs install. If you dont need to go that far you can tag you agents with tags and filter what agent gets used by build. As for the notifications - if they are custom (and by your description the sound like custom) then its your responsibility to provide overrides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On our build team we are currently using the following process for rolling out updates to the build process templates:

1. Create a test build definition that's just for this purpose.(Let's call it 'TestBuild').

   - Clone the existing build definition that you will be extending the build process template for.
   - OR: Create a new build definition
   - Set the Trigger to Manual only
2. Optionally (and if you have permissions to do so) you can set the permissions on the test build definition(s) to hide them from your users.

   - Turn inheritance off in the security page for the build.
   - Explicitly allow visibility of this build definition for you or your group and for no one else
3. Somewhere in your VCS create a folder that you can branch your existing production build process template into.

   - I have a folder under $/Project/Infrastructure/Users/d3r3kk/ for this kind of work.
   - Put your work folder anywhere, ensuring it's someplace that doesn't spark off a build when you check in
4. Branch the existing build process definition into your work folder and check it out for edit.
5. Edit your working copy of the build process definition.
6. Check in your edits once you are done with your feature.
7. If you haven't already, set your TestBuild build definition to make use of the working copy build process template, and mimic the workspace settings that your production build makes use of.
8. Repeat from step 5 until you get the feature correct.

If you or your team are concerned with multiple check-ins that you must do when iterating on this type of feature work, either delete+destroy the working copy when you are done or (better yet) just put the working copy in a folder that no-one regularly pays any attention to. Since the edit / check in process for editing build processes is inherent in TFSBuild, there is really no way to get around the VCS 'noise' that this type of work will cause.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

1. Make build definitions which are specific to branches.
2. Create a training TFS Project/location. I think this is an extreme way to handle it. Dont do this unless you have lot of free space in TFS.

I would just make the new build definition/XAML and add it to a new branch. Make a new build definition with the new XAML copy and then test the changes.